# Circle with arrows in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

So I'm trying something pretty simple, that is to have arrows around a circle, like the blue arrows in the following image

[image]

At the minute, I have a circle, with a stroke, in the stroke flyout menu I have this:

[image]

Which is ok, I just duplicate the circle, rotate it into position (I don't know how to add multiple arrow heads to a stroke.

Is there a better more flexible way that I should be doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to work with multiple strokes instead of one. I don't know of any way to add a number of arrow heads to one stroke unless its done manually.

My idea is to make 5 circles with a stroke no fill. Cut them up in quadrants, so they're as long as you want your arrows. Trim off the access circle, add arrow heads to the front or end. Rotate them so they don't overlap. I just did something similar [image]

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to break a circle up into separate arrows, although I was using a much simpler graphic and this may not work for everyone. I had a simple one-point line circle that was illustrating a cycle of events. I wanted the circle to be a series of arrows following the circle's path, with the arrows between the points on the cycle. I just defined the circles line as 'arrow' in the stroke dialogue box, and then used the scissors tool to cut the circle. The arrowheads inserted automatically at all the cut points. Then I just deleted the parts of the circle where there was text. See the graphic below (note, still in need of a final cleanup, but you get the idea):
[image]